# getElementById not working correctly with MS Access connection

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to connect to a local MS Access DB and display the results, however I can get the results to print using document.write but I have been unable to get getElementById.innerHTML to work at all. Can you see what I am doing wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Search</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="search">
<span id="name" style="font-family:Arial;"><span style="font-size:15px;">Enter name</span></span>
<input maxlength="300" id="myInput" name="myInput" size="30" type="text"/>
<input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="query2();" />
</div>

<div id="content1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function query2() {
var adVarWChar = 202;
var adParamInput = 1;

var pad = "Link_DB.accdb";
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
cn.Open(strConn);
var cm = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cm.ActiveConnection = cn;
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Query11_BR_YTD WHERE Team LIKE ?";
cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
        "?", 
        adVarWChar, 
        adParamInput, 
        255, 
        "%" + document.getElementById("myInput").value + "%"));
var rs = cm.Execute();  // returns ADODB.Recordset object
var table = '';
var tableRow = '';
var headings = true;

if (rs.EOF) {
    document.write("<p>No reports found.</p>");
} else {
    while (!rs.EOF) {
      if (headings) {
        tableRow = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rs.fields.count; i++) {
          switch (i + 1) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
              tableRow = tableRow + '<td>' + rs.fields(i).name + '</td>';
              break;
          }
        }
        tableRow = '<tr>' + tableRow + '</tr>';
        table = table + tableRow;
        headings = false;
      }
      tableRow = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < rs.fields.count; i++) {
          switch (i + 1) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
              tableRow = tableRow + '<td>' + rs.fields(i).value + '</td>';
              break;
          }
      }
      tableRow = '<tr>' + tableRow + '</tr>';
      table = table + tableRow;
      rs.MoveNext();
    }

    document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = "<table id="myTable">" + table + "</table>"; //This is the issue.


}
rs.Close();
cn.Close();
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an error or is nothing happening at all? Is it even getting that far? Can you write the contents to console.log?

Comment: There's a fairly clear syntax error on the `document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = "<table id="myTable">" + table + "</table>"; //This is the issue.` line. Note the quotes.

Comment: It seems like nothing is happening. When submitting I am monitoring the DB and it is not being queried.

Comment: T.J I must be blind, what am I missing here?

Comment: `"<table id="myTable">"`- Either you escape the inner quotes `\"` or you use single quotes `'` for the string or for the attribute